# How to add a background and simple square as a character for a single screen platformer in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I’ve tried adding a background for the game, but as it pops up a second later it goes away It is white and everything else with the background is fine, but this is the only issue. Also, I tried to make a square to use as a character but it just won’t pop up.

```
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import QUIT

background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
(width, height) = (900, 450)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.update()
pygame.init()
dt = 0
x = 30
y = 30
w = 30
h = 30
a = 30
e = 30
l = 30
k = 30


def draw():
    square = pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60), 2)
    pygame.display.flip()


def screen_bound():
    global x
    global y
    global w
    global h
    global a
    global e
    global l
    global k
    # hit right wall
    if ((x+w) > width):
        x = width - w
    # hit floor
    if ((y+h) > height):
        y = height - h
    # hit left wall
    if (x < 0):
        x = 0
    # hit roof
    if (y < 0):
        y = 0

def movement():
    global x
    global y
    GRAVITY = .8
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y = y - (.5*dt)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y = y + (.5*dt)
    y = y = GRAVITY


def handle_events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pass


def start():
    draw()
    movement()
    screen_bound()
    handle_events()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an application loop where you move the objects and redraw the scene in each frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *background.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect.center = window.get_rect().center
speed = 5

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(100)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * speed
    rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * speed
    border_rect = window.get_rect()
    rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)

    # clear the display and draw background
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # draw the scene   
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), rect)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

[image]